# installing npm package taking so long after the computer shut down

Tags: npm, package, installation, expo

I was installing expo in the command prompt . then the computer shut down due to a battery problem. now I am trying to install expo and it seems that the installation is blocked where it was left before the shut down. what should I do to complete the installation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove `package-lock.json` and the `node_modules` folder. After that, your project will be "cleaned" of npm and it's modules.

Run `npm install` once again and all your packages will reinstall like with a clean installation.